# The legend is missing and color changed when I try to print a chart

Tags: c#, printing, charts

I am using nevron(c#) to draw bar charts. However, the printed chart is quite different from the original one (legend is changed to a grey block and line color different ). I do not know what has happened. In the following codes, the NPrintManager is Nevron's, others are from System.Windows.Forms; Does anyone have ideas about that? Thanks in advance.

```
private void toolStripBtPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NPrintManager _printManager = new NPrinManager(_nChartsControl.Document);
        try
        {
            if (_printManager != null)
            {
                PrintDialog dlgPrint = new PrintDialog();
                dlgPrint.UseEXDialog = true;
                if (dlgPrint.ShowDialog(this.ParentForm) == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    _printManager.PrinterSettings =   dlgPrint.PrinterSettings;
                    _printManager.Print();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this.ParentForm, 
                string.Format("Failed to print. Error:{0}", exc.Message), 
                "Print error", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Nevron support and found out it is a bug in Nevron 2010.
Now I upgrade to 2011.1(11.11.1.12), the problem is solved.